# Android: SlidingMenu and ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, slidingmenu, android-actionbaractivity

I'm using the com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu library to create sliding menus, and am using the android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity library for the action bar. In my activity, I am extending ActionBarActivity.

I am able to get a sliding menu by clicking on the home button on the top left. How do I get the entire actionbar to also slide when the home button is clicked?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html Note that nav drawer examples show where both the drawer AND the action bar slide in coordinated fashion. Depend on your needs , the Nav drawer may provide what you want .

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the SlidingMenu's readme: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Here goes the key part: 
You can wrap your Activities in a SlidingMenu by constructing it programmatically (`new SlidingMenu(Context context)`) and then calling `SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(Activity activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW | SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT)`. `SLIDING_WINDOW` will include the Title/ActionBar in the content section of the SlidingMenu, while `SLIDING_CONTENT` does not. You can check it out in the example app AttachExample Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Set your theme as follow, and your Activity extends the SlidingFragmentActivity

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme"  parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</style>
```